# PHP Javascript how to change value of user form, but value has multidata

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i want to ask about how to change value of input in a form, but it has multiple data inside the value.

my form :

```
<form method="post" action="pax-flight.php#pax-flight" class="paxform">
    <input type="hidden" value="{"data":{"user_agent":"sometravel","user_pass":"sometravel","additional":"99507","depart":"SUB","destiny":"CGK","date":"20-06-2015","date2":null,"adult":"1","child":"0","infant":"0"},"0":{"airlines_code":"ID 6401","airlines_name":"lion","airlines_class":"Economy","airlines_seat":1,"airlines_price":"685000","airlines_nta":664450,"airlines_depart":"05:30","airlines_depart_fr":"SUB","airlines_arrive":"07:00","airlines_arrive_to":"CGK","airlines_international":2}}" 
          name="data">

    <div class="search">
         <input class="searchbtn" type="submit" value="Next »">
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

and how i can change a data from the value, example i want to change the date only, or want to change airlines_class only.
is that possible?

*without refreshing the pages, the js can easily change the data, right? but how to change only 1 data inside of the value?

Comment: I guess you are trying to retrieve a `json` object from the value attribute of the `input` tag. Is it?

Comment: json object is all component data, right? i can modify all data but it need to refresh the pages, i just want to automatically change 1 data from value with a click without refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

See the problem is if you are binding json data using some code then you need to use `JSON.stringify` to bind it. In your case the `value` of the input is `{`, which is why you will not be able to access the data as you want. But suppose it is properly bound,

```
<script> 
 var obj={"data":{"user_agent":"sometravel","user_pass":"sometravel","additional":"99507","depart":"SUB","destiny":"CGK","date":"20-06-2015","date2":null,"adult":"1","child":"0","infant":"0"},"0":{"airlines_code":"ID 6401","airlines_name":"lion","airlines_class":"Economy","airlines_seat":1,"airlines_price":"685000","airlines_nta":664450,"airlines_depart":"05:30","airlines_depart_fr":"SUB","airlines_arrive":"07:00","airlines_arrive_to":"CGK","airlines_international":2}};
 window.onload=function(){
 var input=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].type=='hidden') {
        input[i].value=JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/"/g,'\\"');
    }    
   }
 };
</script>
```

In this way your `input` now has the object assigned to its `value`. Now if you want to retrieve any of the data from it you can do

```
  var input=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  //assuming the input tag to be the first tag in the html content
  var retrive=JSON.parse(input);
```

Now you have the object in the `retrive` variable. You can continue your modfication and then re-assign to the hidden `input` tag.

**Fetch**

Example below:

```
function modifyData()
{
   var input =document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].type=='hidden') {
        var retrieve=JSON.parse(input[i].value.replace(/\\"/g,'"'));
        //got the original object
        //Now you can access the objects as follows
        retrieve.data.user_pass="LOTOFTRAVEL";//Initial value - sometravel
        //after modifying the data now putting it back to the value of the input tag
        input[i].value=JSON.stringify(retrieve).replace(/"/g,'\\"');
    }    
   }
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: could you give me example to change 1 data value please?